# spring Jaxb2Marshaller+contextPath+tomcat embedded in maven throws

Tags: maven-2, spring-ws, jaxb2

I'm using spring's Jaxb2Marshaller (without web services) to unmarshal some xml. The xml code is code-gen via maven-jaxb-plugin, and I instantiate the Jaxb2Marshaller in spring via:

```
<bean id="unmarshaller" class="...Jaxb2Marshaller" p:contextPath="my.package.path" />
```

Then start with:

```
mvn clean package
mvn tomcat:run
```

The first unmarshaller is created fine, the second throws with org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.JaxbSystemException because it can't find ObjectFactory (which is generated by the maven-jaxb-plugin, and I've verified is in fact present in the jar, in the correct package).

I actually have two unmarshallers, (although I've tried with one unmarshaller and contextPath with colon separated package paths, with same results).

I don't think this is generally a problem with spring or my configuration, because if I deploy into a full tomcat container it works fine. I did notice that maven puts tomcat in my project/target/tomcat folder and there are some differences, such as there is no lib directory. I actually don't know what all the differences are between embedded tomcat and a regular installation.

Can someone explain:
1) exactly how embedded tomcat differs from a regular installation
2) if there are known limitations
3) if it can be configured to work properly in this situtation

Full stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'unmarshaller' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.JaxbSystemException: "my.package.path" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "my.package.path" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:255)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else who runs across this, I eventually solved the problem by using classesToBeBound property instead of contextPath. The reason I had initially avoided classesToBeBound was that I thought I had to specify every single class in the model in the classesToBeBound list, which isn't the case. You simply specify the class that has the @XmlRootElement annotation.